# How to access different charts in PPT when they share the same name?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Just noticed that in PPT's it is possible for two or more different charts residing in the same slide to share the same name. [See pic]. Was wondering how does PPT allows this in the first place and how then, to access a particular chart ?

Using names to access the charts as shown below, would create ambiguity as they share the same name. Are there any other unique identifiers linked to each chart, which I can make use of ?

```
 Dim FirstChart As Chart
 Set FirstChart= MyPres.Slides.Item(1).Shapes.Item("Chart 2").Chart

 Dim SecondChart As Chart
 Set SecondChart= MyPres.Slides.Item(1).Shapes.Item(???).Chart  'How to access second chart
```

[image]

Comment: There is the shape ID which definitely is unique - but you can only check for that via a for-each-loop - you can't use it as item-index. I would suggest to rename the those charts if possible and to avoid duplicate names

Comment: You can also use a For Each loop to check the chart position using their Top and/or Left properties.

Comment: @Ike There is some bug in renaming too. At times I have noticed that, even after changing names and saving the files, sometime later both end up having same name somehow. That is one reason, why I  am seeking for an alternate efficient way to access charts.

Comment: @JohnKorchok That is a great idea but alas for my particular case the position of chart ain't fixed. One day it could be in right, next day it could be at left.

Comment: This is sounding like a problem that needs to be addressed in the process that is creating these charts. If you can't tell which chart is which programmatically, then there may not be a way to solve it with a macro.